# custom UITableViewCell iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to use `UIView` as a cell in `UITableView`, any suggestions or examples on how to do that?

Answer (score 6):

The UITableViewCell has a readonly property contentView. It returns the content view of the cell object. You can manipulate this view for your needs, add subviews and do what you want.
The 2nd approach is to subclass the UITableViewCell and design it in the interface builder.

Answer (score 1):

You can add in UITableViewCell contentView. I used like following

```
 if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        UILabel* lbl=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 80, 35)];
        lbl.text=@"Email";
        lbl.tag=1;
        lbl.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        lbl.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:20];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl];
}

UILabel* lbl=(UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
lbl.text=@"Your Text";
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom cell by inheriting  UITableviewCell and use that custom cell instead of default table view cell